# How to prevent a kiosk running Ubuntu 13.10 showing the update dialog popup window?

Tags: installation, 13.10, updates, update-manager, privacy

In my KIOSK i have Ubuntu 13.10.

How to remove/suspend/blacklist/hide/disable completely from the Ubuntu 13.10 this following popup via command line? (even with GUI when i click settings and insert my password it still fails and keep repeating it)

- this setup is running in a busy Railway, where passengers passing very busy place 
  every day almost every hour i have this strange popup "Software update" 
  even i do not want it

Please kindly anyone suggest how to remove this to stop disturbing? I have tried following but none works:

```
root@touch:~# vim /etc/default/grub 
add GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
root@touch:~# vim /etc/default/apport 
put 0
root@touch:~# sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
root@touch:~#
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable the update manager popup?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/218755/how-to-disable-the-update-manager-popup)

Answer (score 5):

- install dconf-editor by typing :  `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`
  `
- Now open it using: `sudo dconf-editor`
- go to `com->ubuntu->update-notifer-> no-show-notifications` and
  enable it

.[image]

You can do that same using command line by typing :`dconf write /com/ubuntu/update-notifier/no-show-notifations true`

Comment: I am connected to the machine via SSH i have only SSH access. How do you do that in command line?

Comment: ok, I have added command line method in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, but when i apply `dconf write /com/ubuntu/update-notifier/no-show-notifations true` its giving error: error: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=8d3225b478897bc167810343530e35bd --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1

Comment: Have a look on this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/196307/change-dconf-keys-without-logging-into-x-in-puppet   and http://askubuntu.com/questions/323776/gsettings-not-working-over-ssh